# How can I automate WiFi testing using Xcode Instruments?

Tags: ios, user-interface, xcode7, ios-ui-automation

I want to automate the UI flow on iOS, specifically below steps:

1. User taps on Settings
2. Opens WiFi options
3. Taps on the desired SSID
4. Enters Username and Password
5. Taps connect
6. Opens up a browser

I can do similar flow on Android with Android Debug Bridge. In Xcode Instruments, I don't see any WiFi options listed. Do we have any other tool to automate UI flow on iOS?

Answer (score 2):

The standard is now to use UI Unit tests from XCode. Automation via instruments is deprecated (as far as I know).

However you can automate iOS itself, only the app you are testing. So accessing the settings like this will not work.

I'm also wondering why you need to test this. It's part of iOS and not your app. Therefore it's Apple's job to test it. You can just assume it works.

Comment: I don't want to test any app. All I want to automate is connecting to an SSID. This in turn will test different authentication workflows for me.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this on iOS.  You may want to look into something like http://www.tapster.io.

Also ui_automation is remove from Xcode 8, so theres that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having pretty good luck with http://www.tapster.io